# Finding $(x,y)$ closest to $N$ points

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Given $N$ points where the coordinates of the $i$th point are $(x_i,y_i)$ find $(x,y)$ that minimizes the following sum.
$$\sum_{i=1}^ N\max(|x-x_i|,|y-y_i|)$$
I've done a similar problem minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^ N(|x-x_i|+|y-y_i|)$$
Which I found that the minimum is achieved when we take $x$ as the median of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N$ and $y$ as median of $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N$.

I'm stuck on the first one because I don't know how to manipulate the $\max$.

**Edit 1:**

> After tinkering with the suggestion below I am still struggling to make progress here: The $\frac{|x-x_i|+|y-y_i|}{2}$ can be minimized by taking the median but I am not sure how to minimize the other part: $\frac{||x|-|x_i||-||y|-|y_i||}{2}$. I also don't know what to do if I could minimize the other part. How can I minimize the sum of these two?

Comment: Not a complete answer which finds an expression for the $(x,y)$. However, here is an identity that I think will probably get you where you want to go.
$\max{\{a,b\}} = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{|a-b|}{2}$

Comment: I hope I didn't rob you of more complete answers by putting something more worthy as a comment as an answer. Anyway: I put a suggested edit and deleted my answer to get this back on the list of unanswered questions+ an edit will bump this back on to active questions.

Comment: @Mason Nice of you to do that, I don't think you robbed me of an answer. I feel that the question isn't interesting to people and your observation is helpful.